# network manager indicator disappeared in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: networkmanager, ubuntu-11.04

i just upgraded my ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. I was trying to check out new indicators and i saw this one called indicator-network. I installed it to check it out. It was not showing me the the ad hoc network that i use to connect to the internet. So i removed the indicator. Now, i have no indicator for network. How do i bring the default one back ? Also how do i install it without a network connection? I tried to connect the lan wire to my laptop directly and it does not connect. The lights that come on in the lan wire slot on the laptop, dont come on. Please help me out here.

Comment: Got it fixed. Apparently it removed the package "network-manager"!! I downloaded and installed it from http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/network-manager and everything is normal now

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it once possible to mark this question answered in the system. This'll prevent it from being bumped to the front page every now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed. Apparently it removed the package "network-manager"!! I downloaded and installed it from http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/network-manager and everything is normal now.